# Using Injection in Threads in Websphere 8.5

Tags: ejb, websphere, cdi, executorservice

Im am currently having issues with injection of EJBs in a thread. WildFly, Websphere Liberty >17 and even WebSphere Traditional >9 can deal with injection of EJBs in Threads, but in WebSphere Traditional 8.5 I am experiencing a `NullPointerException` in `ResourceInjectionServiceImpl`.

The JavaEE Specification says that there should be no Threads started in Beans, but not that there should be no injection in "manually created Threads". `InjectionTarget` is used to inject the EJBs and the created instances (after injection) are passed to an `ExecutorService` instance.

My question: Is there a way to get this also working in Websphere Traditional 8.5?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to do injection into manually created threads, mainly because you *should not* being doing that, as stated repetedly in the Java EE specification. You *definitely* should not be creating threads with EJBs, you're almost assured to have memory leaks, lock up your database pools, locking the transaction managers, among many other very common bugs.

Fortunately, if you need concurrency, you have a lot of options. The simplest is to use the `@Asnycronous` annotation. A robust solution is to use JMS and go fully asynchronous. Another option is to inject a  `ManagedExecutorService` and submit tasks to it. Finally, very poor mans concurrency can be had with the Java EE Timer API.

All of these are fully supported and will not cause issues when used properly. However, creating threads is not supported in Java EE and forcing it to work will only create headaches for you later.

Comment: Using @Asynchronous, Timer API  is not an option for me. 
Specification states, that Threads shouldn't be created within EJBs. That is not what I am doing. I am trying to inject EJBs into Threads that are created in a Servlet. I couldn't see, that specs don't allow for this. So for me it looks more as a WAS8.5 bug. For WAS 9 this is working and for Redhat and Oracle Servers as well. MangedExecutorService might be something that I could use. I will have a look at this. What is the main difference of this ManagedExecutorService and the WorkManager (in terms of use cases)?

Comment: It's not a bug, you're using threads, which is not allowed by the spec, unfortunately. Whether you are creating them in EJBs, or creating them and passing them into EJBs, both behaviors are not supported. You have a list of options above to do concurrency, however.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `ManagedExecutorService` which can be obtained through the resource injection. It gives you the capability to execute your tasks in server managed thread pool. Therefore, beans created in service threads can be used in worker threads and vice-versa.

```
@Resource //(lookup="java:comp/DefaultManagedExecutorService")  
ManagedExecutorService managedExecutorService;
```